# ModuleNotFoundError when setting up Google Cloud Function with Cloud Source repository

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, requirements.txt

I am deploying a Google Cloud Function based on code in a BitBucket repository.  I have already linked up the BitBucket account to Google Cloud "Source Repositories" and the Google Function can find the repo, etc.  The problem is that my main.py function needs to call several functions in other packages/modules within my repository.  I have some simple import statements at the top of my main.py file like this:

```
import base64
import json
from datetime import datetime
from competitor_scrape.headless import headless_browser
...
```

The first several lines load fine, but the 4th line (the one that call the module/function within my BitBucket repository) causes this error in Google Functions when I try to define my Google Cloud Function with the main.py in my repository:

```
message:  "Function load error: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in requirements.txt?
Detailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/worker.py", line 211, in check_or_load_user_function
    _function_handler.load_user_function()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/worker.py", line 140, in load_user_function
    spec.loader.exec_module(main)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from competitor_scrape.headless import headless_browser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'competitor_scrape.headless'
```

It asks if I have "list[ed] all of the required modules in requirements.txt".  Am I allowed to list the modules from my own repository?  If so, how should I be doing that?  I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

My current requirements.txt file looks like this:

```
google-cloud-pubsub
numpy==1.14.5
pandas==0.22.0
psycopg2==2.7.4
selenium==3.4.3
geopy==1.11.0
googlemaps==2.5.1
ratelimiter==1.2.0
sqlalchemy==1.2.0
zeep==2.5.0
```

### EDIT/UPDATE

My repository file structure looks something like this right now:

```
.
├── competitor_scrape
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── headless.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

`headless_browser` is a function defined within `headless.py`.  However, at this point my `__init__.py` inside `competitor_scrape` is empty (it was auto-generated by PyCharm).  It seems that the `__init__.py` is probably the root of the problem.  How should I be populating that script so that scripts/functions within `competitor_scrape` are available to the Google Cloud Function?

Comment: Can you provide a rough directory layout? Where is your `main.py` file in relation to the `competitor_scrape` and `headless` directories? Where is `headless_browser` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the issue was pretty simple.  The file `headless.py` was in the local working directory, but was not added to Git revision control, so it was not getting updated in the cloud, and therefore could not be found by GCP.

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same issue with config.py imported in main.py. It looks like if everything in the .gitignore file was also ignored by gcloud functions deploy. I did not see this issue before!

**Error** (with config.py in .gitignore):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

**Error** (after deleting the .gitignore file):

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Could not read ignore file [./.gitignore]: Unable to read file [./.gitignore]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './.gitignore'
```

**Succes** (after adding an empty .gitignore file):

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.                                                                   
availableMemoryMb: 2048
entryPoint: handler
httpsTrigger:
  url: https://europe-west1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
maxInstances: 10
...
```

When I added a .gitignore file **without** config.py, everything worked as expected and I was able to deploy the cloud function! So it seems like .gitignore entries are excluded from the deployment. With previous deployment, I thought this behaviour was supposed to be the job of .gcloudignore.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include the modules in `requirements.txt` -- that's only for dependencies to be installed from PyPI.

An import statement like:

```
from competitor_scrape.headless import headless_browser
```

means that you should have a directory structure something like this:

```
.
├── competitor_scrape
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── headless
│       └── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

And in the `competitor_scrape/headless/__init__.py` file, you should have a variable called `headless_browser`.